# Java - Telegram API calls are too slow

Tags: java, api, http, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm testing Telegram API's send-a-message requests using Java. But it seems there's always a long delay (approximately 2-10sec) to send a message to my channel. Here's my code (tokens are removed for privacy):

```
import com.pengrad.telegrambot.Callback;
import com.pengrad.telegrambot.TelegramBot;
import com.pengrad.telegrambot.model.request.ParseMode;
import com.pengrad.telegrambot.request.SendMessage;
import com.pengrad.telegrambot.response.SendResponse;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TelegramTests {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Create your bot passing the token received from @BotFather
        TelegramBot bot = new TelegramBot("---");

        SendMessage request = new SendMessage("----", "Hello")
                .parseMode(ParseMode.HTML)
                .disableNotification(true);

        int mesId = bot.execute(request).message().messageId();

        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                request = new SendMessage("----", "Hello" + i)
                        .parseMode(ParseMode.HTML)
                        .disableNotification(true);

                bot.execute(request, new Callback<SendMessage, SendResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(SendMessage request, SendResponse response) {
                        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(SendMessage request, IOException e) {

                    }
                });
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

    }
}
```

The code is supposed to send 10 messages, then sleep for a second, then do the same etc. But what it does is it takes 15-20 sec to send these messages. But the speed is crucial for my project. The same issue goes for both sync and async requests. Can I do something about it (webhooks, etc.)?

Thanks in advance

P.S. My server is in Eastern Europe, so this one should not be the case, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Perhaps you hitting API limits? You can send for example 20 messages/minute/group https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this

Comment: It's a private channel, so only 30req per second rule should apply

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was connected to the number of requests I do in my code, reducing it to 3-4 a second seems to have solved it.